Some apps (Chrome, STM32IDE) don't start anymore after updating kernel
After updating Linux kernel to 6.8.0-40-generic, some apps (Chrome, STM32IDE) don't start anymore, i.e. spinner goes on up to 10 seconds then disappears and nothing happens.
dmesg shows a lot of different errors, like :
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] ERROR Atomic update failure on pipe A

nouveau 0000:01:00.0: chrome[3454]: failed to idle channel 2 [chrome[3454]]

DMAR: [DMA Read NO_PASID] Request device

PTE Read access is not set

dmar: drhd: handling fault status reg 2
dmar: drhd: handling fault status reg 3

Xwayland[2807]: failed to idle channel 2

Tried to reboot a bunch of times, no difference. Firefox is still working.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a ASUS Vivo AIO 27 V272UN.

Solved it as follows : open Software & Updates window, go to Additional Drivers tab and select the (proprietary, tested) latest NVIDIA binary driver :

Apply the changes and reboot the PC. Cheers.
